# Angular JS ng-app in multiple spots

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an angular app with a login page and a signup page and a dashboard that a user is able to access once they have logged in. Currently a user can you directly to the login page or the signup page, so I have a `ng-app` at the top of both pages. But this does not seem the right way to do things, and it doesn't make sense to initialize my app more than once. But if I only have the `ng-app` on the login page and a user goes directly to the signup page, the app wont be initialized and I wont have access to the controller for my signup page. How can I get around this?

I would like to just initialize my app once as from what I have read this is how it should be done.

Thank you

Comment: Why are't you using `ng-app` at `index` page? those seems to be partials

Comment: Don't use multiple pages. Use one page with `ng-route` to handle navigation.

Comment: as stated above, it's best if you have only one page. Login, dashboard will be states of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ng-app in an index.html file, then have something like this in the body:

```
<body>
  <div data-ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Then you can use ui-router or ng-route to switch 'states' (ie login, signup etc) and the 'view' will fill into the data-ui-view. Personally I find ui-router to be better, but either can do it.

Comment: but what if I want the person to be able to go direclty to the signup page? how could that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you have to use ng-app once per application. You can manage views using ngRoute module or with ui-router and you can find more options on it.

See example below, there are some extra things you can learn from.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router'])
 .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(evt, to, toParams, from, fromParams, error) {
          if (error.redirectTo) {
            $state.go(error.redirectTo);
          } else {
            $state.go('error', {status: error.status})
          }
        })
    })
 .factory('userService', userService)
 .config(routes);

function userService() {
 var usersMock = {
     'testUser': {
         username: 'testUser',
            password: '1234'
        },
        'testUser2': {
         username: 'testUser2',
            password: '1234'
        }
    };
 var userService = {
     user: undefined,
     login: function(userCredentials) {
         // later --> $http.post('auth', userCredentials).then(...)
            // for demo use local data
            var user = usersMock[userCredentials.username]
            userService.user = ( user && ( user.password == userCredentials.password ) ) ? 
             user : undefined;
            return user;
        },
        logout: function() {
         userService.user = undefined;
        }
    }
    
    return userService;
}
function routes($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    
    $stateProvider
     .state('root', {
         url: '',
         abstract:true,
            resolve: {
             'user': function(userService) {
                 return userService.user; // would be async in a real app
                }
            },
            views: {
             '': {
                 templateUrl: 'layout.html',
                },
             'header@root': {
                 template: '<h1>header View<span ng-if="user"><button ng-click="logout()">logout</button></span><span ng-if="!user"><button ng-click="login()">login</button></span></h1>',
                    controller: function($scope, $state, user, userService) {
                     $scope.user = user;
                        $scope.login = function() {
                         $state.go('login');
                        };
                        $scope.logout = function() {
                         userService.logout();
                            $state.go('root.home', {}, {reload: true});
                        };
                    }
             },
                'footer@root': {
                    template: '<p>footer view</p>'
                }
            }
        })
     .state('root.home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    template: 'Hello at home'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('root.about', {
            url: '/about',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    template: 'about view'
                }
            }
     })
        .state('root.restricted', {
            url: '/restricted',
            resolve: {
             auth: function(userService, $q, $timeout) {
                
                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                 /* //with an async
                    return UserService.load().then(function(user){
                      if (permissionService.can(user, {goTo: state})) {
                        return deferred.resolve({});
                      } else {
                        return deferred.reject({redirectTo: 'some_other_state'});
                      }
                    }*/
                    
                   $timeout(function() {
                        if ( angular.isUndefined(userService.user) ) {
                            return deferred.reject({redirectTo: 'login'});
                        }
                        else {
                            return deferred.resolve(userService.user);
                        }
                    });
                    
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            },
            views: {
                'content': {
                    template: 'this is only visible after login. Hello {{user}}!',
                    controller: function($scope, auth) {
                     $scope.user = auth.username;
                    }
                }
            }
     })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: function($scope, $state, userService) {
             $scope.login = function(cred) {
                 var user = userService.login(cred);
                    
                    if (angular.isUndefined(user)) {
                     alert('username or password incorrect.')
                    }
                    else {
                     $state.go('root.restricted');
                    }
                };
            }
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <a ui-sref="root.home" href="#">home</a>
    <a ui-sref="root.about" href="#">about</a>
    <a ui-sref="root.restricted" href="#">restricted page</a>
    
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="views/login.html">
     <h1>Login</h1>
        <label>Username</label><input ng-model="userCred.username"/>
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" ng-model="userCred.password"/>
        <button ng-click="login(userCred)">login</button>
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="layout.html">
     <div>
            <div ui-view="header"></div>
            <div ui-view="content"></div>
            <div ui-view="footer"></div>
     </div>
    </script>
</div>
```